# What is the best place to store ansible roles

Tags: ansible

I have installed few roles using ansible-galaxy and have included the following line in my .ansible.cfg:

```
roles_path    = /Users/idyllic/ansible/roles
```

Now, for a specific project I have defined a requirement.yml where I have listed all the ansible roles that need to be installed (and they are all stored in /Users/idyllic/ansible/roles).

```
ansible-galaxy install -r requirement.yml
```

Now, even project has a roles directory so is it wise to download the roles in the project roles directory instead of the one defining it on directory define by (.ansible_cfg)

What is the best practice for storing the roles in ansible (version 2.1.1.0)?

Comment: Please let me know why you think downvoting such question help. I will ensure that I don't repeat that in future.

Comment: +1 as it's a good question.  Also, people shouldn't down-vote without a comment or a close-request stating a reason.

Comment: Don't mind the down vote. I am pretty sure there is somebody who downvotes for no reason these days.

Comment: Please consider upgrading. You're using Ansible 2.1... It's EOL for a long time already.

Answer (score 0):

i have this line in my project root folder

```
roles_path = ./roles:..:/etc/ansible/roles
```

and then the requirements.yml installation places then within the project.

This ensures that if a role is part of two projects, its not updated by accident

project tree structure:

```
.
├── Makefile
├── Vagrantfile
├── ansible.cfg
├── defaults
│   └── main.yml
├── elasticsearch.yml
├── handlers
│   └── main.yml
├── meta
│   └── main.yml
├── requirements.yml
├── tasks
│   ├── main.yml
├── templates
├── roles # this is where the requirements.yml go
└── vars
    └── main.yml
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using the project structure from https://github.com/enginyoyen/ansible-best-practises.

It contains a bash script which downloads and updates in a dedicated directory Ansible external roles which are declared in a requirements file:

I find it very easy and very useful to create many different and separated project structures.